# A weird type of defining a function

Tags: c, function, user-defined-functions

I learning C for 1 years, i saw a type of defining a function. I couldn't name it, so i want to know the name of the defining function.

We defining functions as standard:

```
FunctionReturnType FunctionName(FunctionArgs)
{
  codes();
}
```

But i saw that type:

```
FunctionReturnType FunctionName(FunctionArgs)(TheWeirdArea)
{
  codes();
}
```

So what we doing for in i named as TheWeirdArea? I guess it's relative with function arguments, but i want to know correctly what we do in TheWeirdArea.

Comment: It means `FunctionName` returns a function (pointer hopefully) which takes `TheWeirdArea` as parameter and returns `FunctionReturnType`. like `int (*foo(int))(int);`, `foo` takes an `int` and returns a pointer to a function, which takes an `int` and returns an `int`

Comment: You mean `__attribute__` ?

Comment: can we relative it with clockwise/spiral rule stuff?
http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html @mch

Comment: If it is what I guessed in my comment, yes. You can also enter it here: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is about returning a function pointer to a function looking like

```
FunctionReturnType func(TheWeirdArea);
```

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bar1(int b)
{
    printf("bar1\n");
    return 42 + b;
}

int bar2(int b)
{
    printf("bar2\n");
    return 100 + b;
}

int (*foo(int a))(int b)  // Returns a function pointer
{
    if (a == 1) return bar1;
    return bar2;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", foo(1)(100));
    printf("%d\n", foo(2)(200));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bar1
142
bar2
300
```

Comment: Oh! Really thanks! I understand why we use this. Also much thanks to @Yasser Mohamed

Answer (score 0):

Hope this dummy example help you

```
int add(int x,int y)
{
return x+y;   //very dummy function return x+y
}


typedef int (*pointer_to_add)(int,int);
/* this is a declaration of  function pointer works 

with any function has an int return type and

 accept two int arguments not only add */

int (*my_function(int arg1, double arg2))(int, int)
{
   /*This a function accept an int argument 

arg1 and double arg2 and return pointer to a function or address of function

which has a two int type arguments and return an int */

pointer_to_add  ptr=add; //ptr is a pointer now to add function.

return  ptr;
}
```

More simple form

```
pointer_to_add my_function(int arg1,double arg2)
{

 pointer_to_add ptr=add;

 return ptr;

 }
```

Now in your main code you can use the returned address like:

```
 int main(void)
  {
    pointer_to_add P=my_function(25,3.5);
    printf("%i",p(22,33));
    return 0;
    }
```